# How to control the visual controls arrangement at runtime?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have 2 `TLayout` controls with some controls inside (`TLabel`, `TGridLayout`, & `TListView`). I initially set both `TLayout.Visibility` to False at design time.

During runtime, and with same trigger, both `TLayout.Visibility` will change to True at the same time. The screenshot below will show you the visual error:

[image: Overlapphing TLayouts at Runtime]

As you can see, the "variant" layout is overlapping the "size" layout.

Moreover, the "variant" layout should suppose to be precedent over the "size" layout.

Heres the exact arrangement I did at design-time, and it should appear in this manner:

[image]

I realized that the arrangement I did at design-time is not guaranteed to appear that way during runtime, especially in my case.

By the way, my 2 `TLayout` controls are inside a `TVertScrollBox`.

How do I control the arrangement of my visual controls at runtime?

> .FMX file

```
object formMain: TformMain
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Project X Client'
  ClientHeight = 596
  ClientWidth = 405
  StyleBook = stb1
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  OnKeyUp = FormKeyUp
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object tabFooter: TTabControl
    Touch.GestureManager = GestureManager1
    OnGesture = GestureDone
    Align = Client
    FullSize = True
    Size.Width = 405.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 596.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabHeight = 49.000000000000000000
    TabIndex = 0
    TabOrder = 0
    TabPosition = Bottom
    Sizes = (
      405s
      547s
      405s
      547s
      405s
      547s
      405s
      547s)
    object tbiHome: TTabItem
      CustomIcon = <
        item
        end>
      IsSelected = True
      Size.Width = 100.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 49.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      StyleLookup = 'tabitemfavorites'
      TabOrder = 0
      Text = #144'Home'
      ExplicitSize.cx = 101.000000000000000000
      ExplicitSize.cy = 49.000000000000000000
      object tabHome: TTabControl
        Touch.GestureManager = GestureManager1
        OnGesture = GestureDone
        Align = Client
        FullSize = True
        Size.Width = 405.000000000000000000
        Size.Height = 547.000000000000000000
        Size.PlatformDefault = False
        TabHeight = 49.000000000000000000
        TabIndex = 2
        TabOrder = 0
        TabPosition = None
        Sizes = (
          405s
          547s
          405s
          547s
          405s
          547s)


        object tbiItemProfile: TTabItem
          CustomIcon = <
            item
            end>
          IsSelected = True
          Size.Width = 8.000000000000000000
          Size.Height = 8.000000000000000000
          Size.PlatformDefault = False
          StyleLookup = ''
          TabOrder = 0
          Text = #144
          ExplicitSize.cx = 8.000000000000000000
          ExplicitSize.cy = 8.000000000000000000
          object vsbItemProfile: TVertScrollBox
            Align = Client
            Size.Width = 405.000000000000000000
            Size.Height = 503.000000000000000000
            Size.PlatformDefault = False
            TabOrder = 0
            Viewport.Width = 389.000000000000000000
            Viewport.Height = 503.000000000000000000
            object glpItemPhoto: TGlyph
              Margins.Left = 30.000000000000000000
              Margins.Top = 20.000000000000000000
              Margins.Right = 30.000000000000000000
              Margins.Bottom = 10.000000000000000000
              Align = Top
              Position.X = 30.000000000000000000
              Position.Y = 20.000000000000000000
              Size.Width = 329.000000000000000000
              Size.Height = 329.000000000000000000
              Size.PlatformDefault = False
              ImageIndex = 0
              Images = imlImages
            end
            object lblItemBrand: TLabel
              Align = Top
              StyledSettings = [Family, FontColor]
              Margins.Left = 37.000000000000000000
              Margins.Top = 7.500000000000000000
              Margins.Right = 37.000000000000000000
              Margins.Bottom = 2.500000000000000000
              Position.X = 37.000000000000000000
              Position.Y = 366.500000000000000000
              Size.Width = 315.000000000000000000
              Size.Height = 16.000000000000000000
              Size.PlatformDefault = False
              TextSettings.Font.StyleExt = {00070000000000000004000000}
              TabOrder = 1
            end
            object lblItemDesc: TLabel
              Align = Top
              AutoSize = True
              StyledSettings = [Family, Style, FontColor]
              Margins.Left = 37.000000000000000000
              Margins.Top = 2.500000000000000000
              Margins.Right = 37.000000000000000000
              Margins.Bottom = 7.500000000000000000
              Position.X = 37.000000000000000000
              Position.Y = 387.500000000000000000
              Size.Width = 315.000000000000000000
              Size.Height = 15.000000000000000000
              Size.PlatformDefault = False
              TextSettings.Font.Size = 11.000000000000000000
              TabOrder = 2
            end
            object spdAddToCart: TSpeedButton
              Align = Top
              StyledSettings = [Family, Size, FontColor]
              Margins.Left = 120.000000000000000000
              Margins.Top = 20.000000000000000000
              Margins.Right = 120.000000000000000000
              Margins.Bottom = 10.000000000000000000
              Position.X = 120.000000000000000000
              Position.Y = 668.500000000000000000
              Size.Width = 149.000000000000000000
              Size.Height = 44.000000000000000000
              Size.PlatformDefault = False
              StyleLookup = 'speedbuttonstyle'
              Text = 'Add to Cart'
            end
            object lytBottomBuffer: TLayout
              Align = Top
              Position.Y = 722.500000000000000000
              Size.Width = 389.000000000000000000
              Size.Height = 20.000000000000000000
              Size.PlatformDefault = False
              TabOrder = 4
            end
            object lytSize: TLayout
              Align = Top
              Margins.Left = 37.000000000000000000
              Margins.Top = 10.000000000000000000
              Margins.Right = 37.000000000000000000
              Position.X = 37.000000000000000000
              Position.Y = 530.500000000000000000
              Size.Width = 315.000000000000000000
              Size.Height = 118.000000000000000000
              Size.PlatformDefault = False
              TabOrder = 5
              object recSize: TRectangle
                Align = Top
                Size.Width = 315.000000000000000000
                Size.Height = 18.000000000000000000
                Size.PlatformDefault = False
                Stroke.Kind = None
                object lblSize: TLabel
                  Align = Top
                  StyledSettings = [Family, Style, FontColor]
                  Margins.Left = 2.000000000000000000
                  Position.X = 2.000000000000000000
                  Size.Width = 313.000000000000000000
                  Size.Height = 18.000000000000000000
                  Size.PlatformDefault = False
                  TextSettings.Font.Size = 11.000000000000000000
                  Text = 'Please choose the size:'
                  TabOrder = 0
                end
              end
              object gdlSize: TGridLayout
                Align = Top
                ItemHeight = 100.000000000000000000
                ItemWidth = 157.500000000000000000
                Orientation = Horizontal
                Position.Y = 18.000000000000000000
                Size.Width = 315.000000000000000000
                Size.Height = 100.000000000000000000
                Size.PlatformDefault = False
                TabOrder = 1
                object lsvContainer: TListView
                  ItemAppearanceClassName = 'TListItemAppearance'
                  ItemEditAppearanceClassName = 'TListItemShowCheckAppearance'
                  HeaderAppearanceClassName = 'TListHeaderObjects'
                  FooterAppearanceClassName = 'TListHeaderObjects'
                  Transparent = True
                  Align = Contents
                  Size.Width = 157.500000000000000000
                  Size.Height = 100.000000000000000000
                  Size.PlatformDefault = False
                  TabOrder = 0
                  ItemAppearance.ItemHeight = 25
                  ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemObjects.Text.Font.Size = 11.000000000000000000
                  ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemObjects.Text.WordWrap = True
                  ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemObjects.Text.Width = 75.000000000000000000
                  ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemObjects.Text.Height = 25.000000000000000000
                  ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemObjects.Accessory.Width = 10.000000000000000000
                  CanSwipeDelete = False
                  OnItemClick = lsvContainerItemClick
                end
                object lsvSize: TListView
                  ItemAppearanceClassName = 'TListItemAppearance'
                  ItemEditAppearanceClassName = 'TListItemShowCheckAppearance'
                  HeaderAppearanceClassName = 'TListHeaderObjects'
                  FooterAppearanceClassName = 'TListHeaderObjects'
                  Transparent = True
                  Align = Contents
                  Size.Width = 157.500000000000000000
                  Size.Height = 100.000000000000000000
                  Size.PlatformDefault = False
                  TabOrder = 1
                  ItemAppearance.ItemHeight = 25
                  ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemObjects.Text.Font.Size = 11.000000000000000000
                  ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemObjects.Text.Width = 84.000000000000000000
                  ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemObjects.Text.Height = 25.000000000000000000
                  ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemObjects.Accessory.Width = 10.000000000000000000
                  ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemObjects.Accessory.Visible = False
                  CanSwipeDelete = False
                end
              end
            end
            object lytVariant: TLayout
              Align = Top
              Margins.Left = 37.000000000000000000
              Margins.Top = 10.000000000000000000
              Margins.Right = 37.000000000000000000
              Margins.Bottom = 7.500000000000000000
              Position.X = 37.000000000000000000
              Position.Y = 420.000000000000000000
              Size.Width = 315.000000000000000000
              Size.Height = 93.000000000000000000
              Size.PlatformDefault = False
              TabOrder = 6
              object recVariant: TRectangle
                Align = Top
                Size.Width = 315.000000000000000000
                Size.Height = 18.000000000000000000
                Size.PlatformDefault = False
                Stroke.Kind = None
                object lblVariant: TLabel
                  Align = Top
                  StyledSettings = [Family, Style, FontColor]
                  Margins.Left = 2.000000000000000000
                  Position.X = 2.000000000000000000
                  Size.Width = 313.000000000000000000
                  Size.Height = 18.000000000000000000
                  Size.PlatformDefault = False
                  TextSettings.Font.Size = 11.000000000000000000
                  Text = 'Please choose the variant:'
                  TabOrder = 0
                end
              end
              object lsvVariant: TListView
                ItemAppearanceClassName = 'TListItemAppearance'
                ItemEditAppearanceClassName = 'TListItemShowCheckAppearance'
                HeaderAppearanceClassName = 'TListHeaderObjects'
                FooterAppearanceClassName = 'TListHeaderObjects'
                Transparent = True
                ItemIndex = 0
                Align = Top
                Position.Y = 18.000000000000000000
                Size.Width = 315.000000000000000000
                Size.Height = 80.000000000000000000
                Size.PlatformDefault = False
                TabOrder = 1
                ItemAppearance.ItemHeight = 25
                ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemObjects.Text.Font.Size = 11.000000000000000000
                ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemObjects.Text.WordWrap = True
                ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemObjects.Text.Trimming = None
                ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemObjects.Text.Width = 290.000000000000000000
                ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemObjects.Text.Height = 25.000000000000000000
                ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemObjects.Accessory.Width = 10.000000000000000000
                ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemObjects.Accessory.Visible = False
                CanSwipeDelete = False
              end
            end
          end
          object tlbItemCat: TToolBar
            Size.Width = 405.000000000000000000
            Size.Height = 44.000000000000000000
            Size.PlatformDefault = False
            TabOrder = 1
            object lblItemCat: TLabel
              Align = Contents
              StyledSettings = [Family, FontColor]
              Size.Width = 405.000000000000000000
              Size.Height = 44.000000000000000000
              Size.PlatformDefault = False
              TextSettings.Font.Size = 18.000000000000000000
              TextSettings.HorzAlign = Center
              TabOrder = 0
            end
            object spdBackProfile: TSpeedButton
              Action = PreviousTabAction1
              Align = Left
              Enabled = True
              ImageIndex = -1
              Size.Width = 44.000000000000000000
              Size.Height = 44.000000000000000000
              Size.PlatformDefault = False
              StyleLookup = 'arrowlefttoolbutton'
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
    object tbiCart: TTabItem
      CustomIcon = <
        item
        end>
      IsSelected = False
      Size.Width = 100.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 49.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      StyleLookup = 'tabitemcontacts'
      TabOrder = 0
      Text = 'Cart'
      ExplicitSize.cx = 102.000000000000000000
      ExplicitSize.cy = 49.000000000000000000
      object ToolBar3: TToolBar
        Size.Width = 405.000000000000000000
        Size.Height = 44.000000000000000000
        Size.PlatformDefault = False
        TabOrder = 0
        object lblTitle3: TLabel
          Align = Contents
          Size.Width = 405.000000000000000000
          Size.Height = 44.000000000000000000
          Size.PlatformDefault = False
          StyleLookup = 'toollabel'
          TextSettings.HorzAlign = Center
          Text = 'Title'
        end
      end
    end
    object tbiTracker: TTabItem
      CustomIcon = <
        item
        end>
      IsSelected = False
      Size.Width = 100.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 49.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      StyleLookup = 'tabitemsearch'
      TabOrder = 0
      Text = 'Tracker'
      ExplicitSize.cx = 101.000000000000000000
      ExplicitSize.cy = 49.000000000000000000
      object ToolBar4: TToolBar
        Size.Width = 405.000000000000000000
        Size.Height = 44.000000000000000000
        Size.PlatformDefault = False
        TabOrder = 0
        object lblTitle4: TLabel
          Align = Contents
          Size.Width = 405.000000000000000000
          Size.Height = 44.000000000000000000
          Size.PlatformDefault = False
          StyleLookup = 'toollabel'
          TextSettings.HorzAlign = Center
          Text = 'Title'
        end
      end
    end
    object tbiChat: TTabItem
      CustomIcon = <
        item
        end>
      IsSelected = False
      Size.Width = 103.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 49.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      StyleLookup = 'tabitembookmarks'
      TabOrder = 0
      Text = 'Chat'
      ExplicitSize.cx = 99.000000000000000000
      ExplicitSize.cy = 49.000000000000000000
    end
  end
  object stb1: TStyleBook
    Styles = <
      item
      end
      item
        Platform = 'AndroidL Light'
      end>
    Left = 176
    Top = 65528
  end
  object GestureManager1: TGestureManager
    Sensitivity = 80.000000000000000000
    Left = 48
    Top = 209
    GestureData = <
      item
        Control = tabFooter
        Collection = <
          item
            GestureID = sgiLeft
          end
          item
            GestureID = sgiRight
          end>
      end
      item
        Control = tabHome
        Collection = <
          item
            GestureID = sgiLeft
          end
          item
            GestureID = sgiRight
          end>
      end>
  end
  object ActionList1: TActionList
    Left = 48
    Top = 136
    object NextTabAction1: TNextTabAction
      Category = 'Tab'
      TabControl = tabHome
    end
    object PreviousTabAction1: TPreviousTabAction
      Category = 'Tab'
      TabControl = tabHome
    end
  end
  object bdrContainer: TBindSourceDB
    DataSet = dmMain.qryContainer
    ScopeMappings = <>
    Left = 192
    Top = 288
  end
  object bdrSize: TBindSourceDB
    DataSet = dmMain.qrySize
    ScopeMappings = <>
    Left = 200
    Top = 296
  end
  object bdlHome: TBindingsList
    Methods = <>
    OutputConverters = <>
    Left = 116
    Top = 5
    object lcfVariant: TLinkListControlToField
      Category = 'Quick Bindings'
      DataSource = bdrOther
      FieldName = 'variant'
      Control = lsvVariant
      FillExpressions = <>
      FillHeaderExpressions = <>
      FillBreakGroups = <>
    end
    object lcfContainer: TLinkListControlToField
      Category = 'Quick Bindings'
      DataSource = bdrContainer
      FieldName = 'container'
      Control = lsvContainer
      FillExpressions = <>
      FillHeaderExpressions = <>
      FillBreakGroups = <>
    end
    object lcfSize: TLinkListControlToField
      Category = 'Quick Bindings'
      DataSource = bdrSize
      FieldName = 'size'
      Control = lsvSize
      FillExpressions = <>
      FillHeaderExpressions = <>
      FillBreakGroups = <>
    end
    object lcfMeta: TLinkListControlToField
      Category = 'Quick Bindings'
      DataSource = bdrMeta
      FieldName = 'meta'
      Control = lsvMeta
      FillExpressions = <>
      FillHeaderExpressions = <>
      FillBreakGroups = <>
    end
    object lcfItems: TLinkListControlToField
      Category = 'Quick Bindings'
      DataSource = bdrItem
      FieldName = 'name'
      Control = lsvSearches
      FillExpressions = <
        item
          SourceMemberName = 'description'
          ControlMemberName = 'Detail'
        end>
      FillHeaderExpressions = <>
      FillHeaderFieldName = 'category'
      FillBreakGroups = <>
    end
    object lpfItemCat: TLinkPropertyToField
      Category = 'Quick Bindings'
      DataSource = bdrItem
      FieldName = 'category'
      Component = lblItemCat
      ComponentProperty = 'Text'
    end
    object lpfItemBrand: TLinkPropertyToField
      Category = 'Quick Bindings'
      DataSource = bdrItem
      FieldName = 'name'
      Component = lblItemBrand
      ComponentProperty = 'Text'
    end
    object lpfItemDesc: TLinkPropertyToField
      Category = 'Quick Bindings'
      DataSource = bdrItem
      FieldName = 'description'
      Component = lblItemDesc
      ComponentProperty = 'Text'
    end
  end
  object bdrItem: TBindSourceDB
    DataSet = dmMain.qryItems
    ScopeMappings = <>
    Left = 208
    Top = 304
  end
  object bdrOther: TBindSourceDB
    DataSet = dmMain.qryVariant
    ScopeMappings = <>
    Left = 216
    Top = 312
  end
  object bdrItems: TBindSourceDB
    DataSet = dmMain.qryVariants
    ScopeMappings = <>
    Left = 224
    Top = 320
  end
  object bdrMeta: TBindSourceDB
    DataSet = dmMain.qryMeta
    ScopeMappings = <>
    Left = 232
    Top = 328
  end
end
```

**REMOVED THE PROCEDURES**
*for its no longer relevant*

**UPDATE CASE OF TLABELS THIS TIME**

I have changed already arrangement to accommodate the issue here. But then again, I encounter almost the same issue on the TLabels. I have to TLabel named labelTitle and labelDescription. There arrangement is Title over Desc. But when I ran it, the labelDesc jumped to the bottom part preceded by all other components.

Here's the screenshot:
[image]

Here's also the .fmx file:

```
        object tbiItemProfile: TTabItem
          object vsbItemProfile: TVertScrollBox
            Align = Client
            Viewport.Width = 389.000000000000000000
            Viewport.Height = 503.000000000000000000
            object lytItemProfile: TLayout
              Align = Top
              object lytDetails: TLayout
                Align = Top
                object lytAddToList: TLayout
                  Align = Top
                  object lytQtyToOrder: TLayout
                    Align = Left
                    object lytUpDownQty: TLayout
                      Align = Bottom
                      object spdDown: TSpeedButton
                        Align = MostLeft
                      object spdUp: TSpeedButton
                        Align = MostRight
                    object edtQty: TEdit
                      Align = Client
                  object spdAddToList: TSpeedButton
                    Align = Right
                object recVariant: TRectangle
                  Align = Top
                  object lytContainer: TLayout
                    Align = Left
                    object lblContainer: TLabel
                      Align = Top
                    object lsvContainer: TListView
                      Align = Top
                  object lytSize: TLayout
                    Align = Client
                    object lsvSize: TListView
                      Align = Top
                    object lytSizePrice: TLayout
                      Align = Top
                      object lblPriceRange: TLabel
                        Align = Client
                      object lblSize: TLabel
                        Align = Left
                object gdlOptions: TGridLayout
                  Align = Top
                  object spdBack: TSpeedButton
                    Align = Client
                  object spdCancel: TSpeedButton
                    Align = Client
                  object spdCanvass: TSpeedButton
                    Align = Client
                  object spdMore: TSpeedButton
                    Align = Client
              object lblItemName: TLabel.              // labelItemName
                Align = Top
              object lblItemDesc: TLabel               // labelItemDescription      
                Align = Top
              object glpItemPhoto: TGlyph
                Align = Top
          object tlbItemCat: TToolBar
            object lblItemBrand: TLabel
              Align = Contents
            object spdItemProfileBack: TSpeedButton
              Align = Left
            object spdItemProfileNext: TSpeedButton
              Action = NextTabAction1
              Align = Right
```

Comment: Please show your `.fmx` file and the complete procedure that makes the layouts visible. Which Delphi version?

Comment: @TomBrunberg I am not sure if I can give you all but I can come up RME for this. Give me a moment.

Comment: I tried RME and it works! No choice but to give you the complete file but to my surprise its a huge .fmx file and SO allowed only to 30,000 characters.

Comment: Well, you could cut out from the `.fmx` items that are not related, but so that the full chain from the form to the `ListView`s is fully included.

Comment: Thanks. I already updated with the files you requested. Please bear with my way of coding not really good ones.

Comment: Basically, the height of my TLayouts are variable and dependent on the number of items to be shown in my TListView which is inside the TLayout. That I suspect is the culprit. But I need to do it that way avoid vertical scroll bar to appear so the view of the my list is shown upfront.

Comment: I have managed to create a test project based on code you provided. I also see the problem, and been able to eliminate in some cases, but not all, so the final cure is still under dev. I continue tomorrow.

Comment: @TomBrunberg No worries. Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry, I totally forgot. I just posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for the `Size` layout to occur before the `Variant` layout is the order in which they were defined at design time.

(This could also explain why your separately made test did work correctly, as you probably declared `lytVariant` before `lytSize`, in their logical order.)

Looking at an extract from your `.fmx` file (I have removed settings that are irrelevant in this discussion), and since `lytSize` occurs before `lytVariant` it is also displayed first.

Swap their order in the `.fmx` file. Be careful though, indentation (with spaces only) is a key factor in the file.

```
object formMain: TformMain
  object tabFooter: TTabControl
    object tbiHome: TTabItem
      object tabHome: TTabControl
        object tbiItemProfile: TTabItem
          object vsbItemProfile: TVertScrollBox
            Align = Client
            object glpItemPhoto: TGlyph
              Align = Top
            end
            object lblItemBrand: TLabel
              Align = Top
            end
            object lblItemDesc: TLabel
              Align = Top
            end
            object spdAddToCart: TSpeedButton
              Align = Top
            end
            object lytBottomBuffer: TLayout
              Align = Top
            end

            object lytSize: TLayout
              Align = Top
              object recSize: TRectangle
                Align = Top
                object lblSize: TLabel
                  Align = Top
                  Text = 'Please choose the size:'
                end
              end
              object gdlSize: TGridLayout
                Align = Top
                object lsvContainer: TListView
                  Align = Contents
                end
                object lsvSize: TListView
                  Align = Contents
                  ItemAppearance.ItemHeight = 25
                end
              end
            end

            object lytVariant: TLayout
              Align = Top
              object recVariant: TRectangle
                Align = Top
                object lblVariant: TLabel
                  Align = Top
                  Text = 'Please choose the variant:'
                end
              end
              object lsvVariant: TListView
                Align = Top
                Position.Y = 18.000000000000000000
              end
            end
          end
```

Then, another problem might be that both `lytVariant` and `lytSize` are dynamically populated (from a db I guess). You may have to hide and redisplay, in correct order, everything from `lytVariant` to the end, when new data is fetched from the db.

Comment: Thanks so much Tom. I'll will look into this tomorrow first thing in the morning. I'll have to take some rest in the meantime after whole day coding and my eyes are so weary. Get back to you tomorrow.

Comment: Hi Tom. You mean the reason why lytSize overlap lytVariant or precedes lytVariant at runtime is because the order arrangement in my .fmx file?

Comment: As in my very first sentence, or as you express it: `lytSize` precedes `lytVariant` at runtime because it (`lytSize`) is defined before in the .fmx file. If you swap their order in .fmx, are they still overlapping? I was never able to reproduce the overlapping.

Comment: No, I can no longer be able to check because I have modified already the arrangement. I have merged the lytSize and lytVariant side-by-side using TRectangle (to avail of the border). However, this issue still relevant to me but in different components. This time it is the TLabels (lableTitle over lableDescription) thrown down to the very bottom (precedes by all other components). I checked my .fmx and the order arrangement of my TLabels are correct (no components in between).

Comment: I don't see any components with the names `lableTitle` and `lableDescription` in the files I have here, so I can't say anything about those.

Comment: No, its not actually there. I'll give an update to my question.

Comment: I have posted the update for the labelTitle and labelDescription with screenshot and .fmx file. Though both of them are sequentially order (one over the other) in the .fmx file but at its entirety looks not sequential as I arranged at design time.

Comment: But you know what. This only happens with iOS, not sure yet with Android, but on Windows the order is fine.